# Does the IOT Edge 1.4 inside EFLOW 1.4 include the latest Cypher suite requirements?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

Reference:  Azure IoT TLS: Critical changes are almost here! (…and why you should care) - Microsoft Community Hub
Does the IOT Edge 1.4 inside EFLOW 1.4 or the EFLOW VM OS include the latest Cypher suite requirements coming for IOT Hub on June 6th?  i.e. the comment by Msoft regarding IOT Hub updates:  Check the Root cert and also ‘ testing endpoints for SHA-256’

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes but I have to write more than 30 characters.